# How to replace first two matches by using vim?

Tags: vim

example:

```
cat abc.txt
foo g foo a foo
```

I just wanna replace first and second foo to goo.
How should I do this in VIM?

output:

```
goo g goo a foo
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to do this.

1. Starting in Normal mode, `/foo<CR>3sfoo<Esc>n.`.
2. Switch to Command mode:  `:s/foo/goo<CR>&`.
3. Use extended regular expressions: `:s/foo\(.\{-}\)foo/goo\1goo`.

(#3 will fail if "foo" does not appear twice.)

```
:help s
:help .
:help &
:help sub-replace-special
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not a golfer and don't want to purposely do things under a character constraint, how about just running :%s/foo/goo/ twice?

Answer (score 0):

With my [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602), you can specify the matches as counts or `yynyny` answers to a special `:SubstituteSelected` variant of `:substitute`:

```
:SubstituteSelected/foo/goo/g 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all the other answers, you can also try :

`:%s/foo/goo/gc`

this will ask for `replace with abc (y/n/a/q/l/^E/^Y)?` answer `y` for first two times then enter `q` to exit.